# Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault, restarting kernel

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, spyder, torch

I am using a macbook pro with the M1 chip.

I have encounter such problem when using  version for

```
Spyder 5.3.3.
python is 3.9.13, 
torch version is 1.13.1. 
The environment I am using is setted up by Anaconda 2.3.1.
```

I have discovered the following 4 line script alone can trigger ths problem

```
import torch

mu0 = torch.tensor([0, 0])

sigma0 = torch.tensor([[1, 0.], [0., 1. ]])

PDF=torch.distributions.multivariate_normal.MultivariateNormal(mu0,sigma0)
```

To be exact, it is the last line that triggered this error. If I run the whole script, the kernel will restart without telling me why. While if I run it line by line, when I run the last line, this message will appear.

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault


Thread 0x0000000313346000 (most recent call first):
  File Fatal Python error: 

Restarting kernel...
```

I have read other similar questions, but each of them seems to be code specific.

Also, I have tried the fix in this link but it does not solve my problem

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659#issuecomment-961306197

Comment: Either anaconda or torch do not support M1 correctly.

Comment: Read `torch.distributions.multivariate_normal.MultivariateNormal` method via: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/distributions/multivariate_normal.py#L97 Run the demo example see if that works.  Either it's a bug in the library, or the input is so wrong that it doesn't bother to inform you why.  Put print statements inside `MultivariateNormal` method and observe each variable as it executes, then report back which line is producing the segmentation fault.  Either your input is trivial and makes no sense, or there's a bug in torch, which wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: I have tried, the same error appears. Also, I tried to run the same line in pycharm and it run correctly, so I guess it is something with anaconda or spyder.